# How to organize routing in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I have component `SkeletonComponent` with tabs inside:

```
<div class="tabs">
   <div class="tab" *ngIf="showTab(1)"><app-journal></app-journal></div>
   <div class="tab" *ngIf="showTab(2)"><app-journal-extended></app-journal-extended></div>
</div>
```

So, there is mechanism that activate tab by condition. It is placed in parent component `SkeletonComponent`.

Now I want to add routing, to activate specific tab by route:

```
  { path: "skeleton", component: SkeletonComponent,  children: [
      {
    path: "journal",
    component: JournalComponent
  },
  {
    path: "journal/:id",
    component: JournalExtendedComponent
  }
  ]},
```

It is right approach?

Comment: What is problem? Looks it working

Comment: if you're trying to activate a tab based on a route parameter, you can subscribe to the parameters in the `ngOnInit` and display appropriate tab based on whatever parameter you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to let the router handle this, don't use the components inside the template. use router-outlet. This example is using Tabs from Material Component. Please change it to your UI specifics. You will also need to change your child route path for the JournalExtendedComponent to `journal/details/:id`

**skeleton.component.html**

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
    <button mat-tab-link *ngFor="let item of menuItems" (click)="selectTab(item)" [active]="activeTabIndex == item.id">{{item.title}}</button>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**skeleton.component.ts**

```
export class JobsForTutorComponent {
  menuItems: MenuItem[] = [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: 'Tab Title 1',
      route: '/route-to-component',
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Tab Title 2',
      route: '/route-to-other-component'
    }
  ];
  activeTabIndex: number;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    const routedMenuItem = this.menuItems.find(menuItem => menuItem.route === this.router.url);
    if (routedMenuItem) {
      this.selectTab(routedMenuItem);
    } else {
      this.activeTabIndex = 0;
    }
  }

  selectTab(tabItem: MenuItem) {
    this.activeTabIndex = tabItem.id;
    this.router.navigate([tabItem.route]);
  }
}
```

**menu-item.model.ts**

```
export interface MenuItem {
    id?: number;
    title?: string;
    route?: string;
}
```

Edit: Routing in your case

```
{
    path: "journal",
    component: SkeletonComponent,
    children: [
      {
       path: "overview",
       component: JournalComponent
      },
      {
       path: "detail/:id",
       component: JournalExtendedComponent
      }
  ]
}
```

menuItems array in your Component will then be:

```
menuItems: MenuItem[] = [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: 'Overview',
      route: '/overview',
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Details',
      route: '/detail'
    }
  ];
```

Comment: Could you provide routing rules? No problem id already exist route-outlet in project?

Comment: Sorry, I had to change the route paths since it won't work with your specific case, I guess. You could have a component which has the path '/journal' and that leads to the SkeletonComponent. Then you provide two components: JournalOverviewComponent witch is selected by child route '/overview' and another one JournalDetailComponent with route '/detail/:id'

Comment: Then in your SkeletonComponent the menuItems array has the items for route '/overview' and '/detail'

Comment: How to use dinamic route instead static? Here  `this.router.navigate([tabItem.route]);` I need url like '/details/:id'

Comment: Or just `:id` rule

Comment: When I listen route url I get this: `detail/44445454` and I can not compare it with rule from tabs object, cause it is dinamic

Comment: Yeah, you‘re right. The example is not right for route paramters. Have you tried this.router.url.includes(menuItem.route) instead of === operator?